# What's the full page background (cover) image technique that twitter uses for their front page (sign in /signed out page)?

Tags: css, twitter, background-image

It seems like CSS - only technique #2 mentioned on: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ but, it's not. There is slight change in the code (wrt to height & display properties)

I tried copy pasting their html css but, I can't get it to work. Is there may be some javascript involved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**its just CSS  no JavaScript**  [WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/utiduc/1)

**CSS**

```
.front-bg {
position: fixed;
width: 200%;
height: 200%;
left: -50%;
background: black;
}

.front-bg img {
display: block;
margin: auto;
min-width: 50%;
min-height: 50%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="front-bg"><image src="http://a0.twimg.com/a/1349296073/t1/img/front_page/city-balcony@2x.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow this is not working nicely (as in scaling the image as I want) but, I guess the problem is that my image is bigger than the window size unlike twitter's

Comment: can you give link to your image so may be i can help?

Comment: here's what i need it to look like: http://jsbin.com/utiduc/2  the problem is I achieved the effect with width: 50% instead of min-width now, that would create a problem on tablets.

Comment: Why are they using a 200% width/height `<div>` and adding an `<img>` inside? Why aren't they using a 100% `<div>` alone and set the image as the background image? Is it because the `<img>` loads faster, or rather its loading process is started earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   background-image:url(relative/path/to/image);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-attachment:fixed;
}

#container {
   margin:0 auto;
   width:900px; /* your fixed width */
}
```

Comment: sorry editing my question...i think it confusing...I meant full page as in cover image not just full width.

Comment: No, Width is only for your container content